# Adding Node to TreePanel with a Button. Newbie How To?

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

I have a button that I put an click event on.

I also have a TreePanel loaded with static JSON.

The TreePanel has an ItemID of projectTree

Inside my button click event I have:

```
var treeNode = projectTree.getRootNode();
treeNode.expandChildren(true); // Optional: To see what happens
treeNode.appendChild({
        name: 'Child 4',
        leaf: true,
        element : 6
});
treeNode.getChildAt(2).getChildAt(0).appendChild({
        name: 'Grand Child 3',
        leaf: true,
        element: 7
});
```

It does not add the nodes.   What am I doing wrong?

### **Edited**

```
var treeNode =  this.child('#projectTree').getRootNode();
treeNode.expandChildren(true); // Optional: To see what happens
treeNode.appendChild({
        name: 'Child 4',
        leaf: true,
        element : 6
});

// This one does not work
treeNode.childNodes(0).nextSibling.appendChild({
        name: 'Grand Child 3',
        leaf: true,
        element: 7
});
```

Comment: Where/how is the variable `projectTree` defined? Are there any errors? What version of ExtJS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to the TreePanel first, you can't just use the [itemID](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-itemId) as reference. There are many way of doing this, the simplest is to use [Ext.getCmp](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext-method-getCmp):

```
var projectTree = Ext.getCmp('projectTree');
```

This is assuming you only have 1 component with that itemID, if not, it's better to use [ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery), this is also my prefered method. Example, if your TreePanel is in a Container with an itemID "TreePanelContainer":

```
var projectTree = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#TreePanelContainer > #TreePanel');
```

**UPDATE:**

Is it neccessary to use `nextSibling`? Why don't you use `childNodes[1]`?

```
treeNode.childNodes[1].appendChild({
```

Fiddle: [fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1rb](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1rg)

Also maybe I'm wrong but I've checked the document and there's no `element` config for TreeNode. Maybe you're using an odler version code. Try the offical documents from Sencha page.

Comment: I only use unique ID's assuming that is best but I edited my code and the top addition adds fine now.  But the bottom append is not working.

Comment: What version of ExtJs are you using? I don't see `element` config for TreeNode in the docs. Also here's a Sample fiddle: [link](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1rb)

Comment: Is it neccessary to use `nextSibling`? Why don't you use `childNodes[1]`? Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1rb